# Создание репозитория svn

Tags: svn

Как правильно создать репозиторий в svn, что бы в нем были trunk, branches, tags. Создаю репозиторий следующей командой:

```
svnadmin create /home/svn/some_repo
```

Но впоследствии вышеуказанных папок там нет, а как их добавить, не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Их надо просто создать

```
svn mkdir /home/svn/some_repo/tags -m "added Tags"
svn mkdir /home/svn/some_repo/branches -m "added Branches"
svn mkdir /home/svn/some_repo/trunk -m "added Trunk"
```

или создать временную директорию со структурой и:

```
svn import /home/dir_struct_temp -m "Initial folder structure"
```

ЗЫ Последний вариант использует tortoisesvn при создании репозитория.